# Can't use subclass of AuthenticationException

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, exception, spring-security

I am trying to make an exception subclass of `AuthenticationException` as follows:

```
public class RegistrationNotCompleteException extends AuthenticationException {
    public RegistrationNotCompleteException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }
}
```

and in the `loadUserByUsername` of my `UserDetailsService` class I make the following check:

```
if (!user.getHasRegistered()) {
    System.out.println("######## User: " + username
        + " has not completed the registration");
    throw new RegistrationNotCompleteException(
        "User has not completed registration");
}
```

so the user is forwarded to the `AuthenticationFailureHandler` class as expected.

But when trying to get the exception class in the `onAuthenticationFailure` method as follows:

```
public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception)
    throws IOException, ServletException {

    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token =
        (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) exception.getAuthentication();
    String username = token.getName();
    String credentials = token.getCredentials().toString();
    System.out.println("Exception class: " + exception.getClass());
```

it prints that the exception class is `AuthenticationException` not `RegistrationNotCompleteException`.

And I want to verify that the exception class is `RegistrationNotCompleteException`.

Please advise how to do that.

Comment: Good question. But may I ask you why do you want to extend the authentication exception?  It does not seem that you add any functionality.

Comment: @AlexR, i want to make a new exception RegistrationNotCompleteException to act as a marker that i can check on it in the AuthenticationFailureHandler

Comment: @AlexR, any advise to accomplish what i want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by changing the check to `exception.getCause().getClass()` instead of `exception.getClass()`

Comment: @tcb, forgot to accept it, since you should accept next day of the answer.